# How to Split the String and integer in Sql to find the max and put it in SP or functions to call

Tags: sql-server, function

I have a Retailer code  ,It is combination of `varchar and Int =>RT003880` like this

I have create a Retailer code as script-wise every day. So i need the last Retailer code i have inserted.

So I have split the `Integer and varchar` for finding the Max value.

This is the max value by using Query.

```
select SUBSTRING(Retailer_code,5,9) as RetailerCode
Into #maxfindtable
from dbo.sample
select MAX(RetailerCode) from #maxfindtable
```

I need to put in in function or Stored Procedure how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select max(SUBSTRING(RetailerCode,3,len(RetailerCode)-2))
```

> for RT003880 the integer part is starting from position `3`,and
>   `len(RetailerCode)-2` isdefine the length of the `substring`. i.e: all the
>   character starting from `3`rd position

See [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) for more clearification.

> EDIT 2:

try Using `Cast`

```
create table #tab (genId varchar(max))

insert into #tab(genId)
values('RT00031'),('RT00013232'),('RT00034'),('RT00084')

select * from #tab

select max(cast(SUBSTRING(genId,3,len(genId)-2) as int)) from #tab
```

Comment: Today I have inserted new 10000 records. The Maximum count is RT00017891. But it shows RT0009999. why it happens
After I have Checked a sample data
`RetailerId RetailerCode  RetailerName <br/>
1   RT00031 mBigBazar
2  RT00034 TBazar
3  RT00084 SaravanaStore


It shows Correct Value - 00084 , When I have insert a new Record it shows wrongly

RetailerId RetailerCode  RetailerName
1   RT00031 mBigBazar
2  RT00034 TBazar
3  RT00084 SaravanaStore
4 RT00013232 NewStore `
Now it shows 00084 .why it shows wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the RetailerCode into two columns (one CHAR/VARCHAR and one INT/SMALLINT/NUMERIC) to be able to get some performance out of the table. Possibly use a calculated column to concatenate them if requested. I would never query on the calculated column if it was not persisted, however.

Answer (score 0):

Today I have inserted 10000 new records,its choosing wrong max value. Both The codes Written Same Value,Maximum Value is RT0017898,But It shows RT0009999. 
After I have Checked a sample data 
`RetailerId RetailerCode   RetailerName 
            1   RT00031 mBigBazar 
            2   RT00034 TBazar 
            3   RT00084 SaravanaStore It shows Correct Value - 00084
When I have insert a new Record it shows wrongly 
RetailerId RetailerCode RetailerName 
1   RT00031 mBigBazar 
2   RT00034 TBazar 
3   RT00084 SaravanaStore 
4 RT00013232    NewStore`
 Now it shows 00084 .why it shows wrong?

Comment: Did you find Solution ?